# Cloud.GetAvailableClouds() Error with c#?

Tags: c#, windows, networking

I get this error when I run this piece of code and I don't know what is causing it.

```
foreach (Cloud c in Cloud.GetAvailableClouds())
    Console.WriteLine("Name : {0}", c.Name);
```

When the Cloud.GetAvailableClouds() function is called I get the error:

> Win32Exception: WSAStartup cannot function at this time because the underlying system it uses to provide network services is currently unavailable.

Comment: Where, how and in which context do you run this code? Is this on your own box? Which OS? Which .Net framework?

Comment: i used visual studio an i run it there. On windows. I have used System.Net.PeerToPeer.